# How to make more room on my hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, opensuse

I have openSUSE and Debian on my hard drive, along with several other partitions.
I want to download a live .iso file to make a new live USB and erase everything on my computer.
I tried downloading an .iso file, and when the download failed, it said my disk was full.

```
mike@linux-u32c:~> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        20G  6.0G   13G  33% /
devtmpfs        485M  485M     0 100% /dev
tmpfs           496M   84K  496M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           496M  3.1M  493M   1% /run
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           496M  3.1M  493M   1% /var/run
tmpfs           496M  3.1M  493M   1% /var/lock
/dev/sda6        18G   18G   80M 100% /home

mike@linux-u32c:~>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you set the download location as the USB stick you intend to use and download straight onto that?

Comment: ok, i didn't consider doing that. that would get the file on the usb stick.

Comment: but with respect to making more room on the partition, how would i go about doing that?